# 'ddlCaseFiles' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I have a stored procedure that returns a bunch of FileIds, names etc. I have a DropDownList that I have disabled and I am putting the FileID in the DropDownList so that it will be the only value in the dropdownlist. But I keep getting that error in the title. 
This is what I have:

```
try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            ddlCaseFiles.SelectedValue = reader["FileID"].ToString();//ddl never gets the fileID assigned.
            ddlCaseFiles.Enabled = false;
            txtTimeTrackerDate.Value = reader["TBDate"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: have you assigned valuefield property of dropdown when you are binding dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to add new item to ddlCaseFiles, then:

```
ddlCaseFiles.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["FileID"].ToString()));
```

Check whether or not the value exist in ddlCaseFiles:

```
if (ddlCaseFiles.Items.FindByValue(reader["FileID"].ToString()) != null)
{
  ddlCaseFiles.SelectedValue = reader["FileID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Well, the DropDownList is empty because I am loading an empty one. I want to keep it empty. That is why I disable it, then only want to add in 1 FileID.

Comment: I want to only add that one specificvalue to the ddl. I don't know why the program thinks I am looking for it.

Comment: @user1084319 see my updated answer. You have to use 'ddlCaseFiles.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["FileID"].ToString()));'
 to add new item to your dropdownlist.

Comment: Ah thank you. I see now. However I did manage to get it to work. But I think your method is perhaps more efficient. What I neglected was to set the data properties in the Page_load so it had nothing in it.